# Kotlin: kill a non-cooperative coroutine

Tags: kotlin-coroutines

I have an external library with long calculation. This library is everything, but cooperative in regard of premature stopping. It is wrapped and started within a coroutine.

I would like to kill the process from the caller side. Coroutine cancell is cooperative, so it doesn't work. Is there any way to terminate the coroutine abruptly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A non-suspending coroutine can be abruptly killed only by killing the thread it's executing on, and Java has deprecated all methods of abruptly stopping a thread. They are deprecated for a good reason: threads aren't a unit of isolation like processes are. Aborting a thread can have arbitrary consequences on the state of the surviving process.

The cleanest option for launching long-running, non-cooperatively abortable work is to start a sub-process doing it.

Comment: While it makes perfect sense what you're saying, what do we do if we want to wrap legacy code with threads or coroutines? What do we do?